# buildind front end with reacts using the Axios get response

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

I am new to react js,
I have a home screen with search bar.
now when the user searches for, lets say, an employee name, I'd want to query it against my db, like, select username from employee where employee.name = "whatever the user is searching for".

I finally got a way to send the search parameter to my api and am getting the results in the console log and here is the code for that:

```
const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = useState("");
<input
            value={name}
            type="text" 
            id="header-search"
            placeholder="Enter the search term"
            name={'id'}
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
        
        <button onClick={HandleSearch}>Search</button>

const handleChange= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

const HandleSearch = e => {

    
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/search?id=`+name)
        .then(response => {
          setLoading(false);
          if(response.status == 200 && response != null){
            
              console.log("RES",response.data);
              var tmpArray= [];
              var tmpJsx =[];
              // I was checking to see if I could retrieve the data from my response.
              var dataparse = response.data;
              var length = dataparse.length;
              console.log("length of my response array is: "+length)

              //printing the elements in array
              for (var i=0; i< length; i++){
                
                //console.log(response.data[i].firstname);
                
                 setFirstNames((firstNames) => [...firstNames, response.data[i]]);
                
              }

              
          } else{
                console.log('problem fetching');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log("error occured: "+error);
        });
}
```

and here's my return function:

```
{firstNames.map(function (names, index) {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td> {names.firstname} -</td>
                      <td> {names.lastname}</td>
                    </tr>
                   )
                })}
```

How do I add the headers to this data.
for example

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
```

i tried to put this in the map function, but then my data was looking like:

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
firstname lastname
def        deflast
firstname lastname
ghi        ghilast
```

Im sure there is something that im missing, could anyone help me on how to achieve this: thank you.

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
def        deflast
ghi        ghilast
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you want, but a lot depends on your architecture and what your goals are. What flavour of SQL are you running? (mysql, postgre, etc etc). Do you intend for this app to work in a production environment or are you just learning the ropes? Are you connecting to a server or are you wanting to connect to the database directly react? Have you followed any tutorials?

Comment: yes, i did look at few tutorials, but none of them seem to be useful. to answer your questions,: im querying against mysql, yes ultimate goal is to work it on the prod envt. would want to connect to the db directly.

Comment: Ok. If you intend to go to production, then it would be better to connect to a server (I'm not even sure it's possible to connect directly with React). If the app connects directly to the database then anyone with access to the app also has access to the database and credentials. All tutorials/examples connect to a server to achieve this because this is how it should be done. I strongly advise you follow the same path! This link shows how to get the server side set up and is trivial to change it to what you need.

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/react/reactjs+connect+to+ms+sql+server

Comment: You could then implement a button to post to a search form the Express endpoint the term entered into the search box, or alternatively you could use hooks. You could set a variable using useState that is updated with onChange on the input box, and useEffect to execute a post request (perhaps using Axios) to your Express endpoint when the search value changes. I thin the issue you have been finding is you have been trying to implement something that shouldn't not be implemented, but if you follow the recommended path you'll find the tutorials a lot more useful!

Comment: Hi, so I did some research and was finally able to retrieve the API using axios. Now, my response includes array[10], which while expanding the array. it shows something like: 0: Object{name: ABC, age: 20, ....} 1: Object{...}, can someone help me on how do i render this to display on the browser? please and thanks

Comment: If you paste you're code so far then somebody can provide you an exact answer on how to do it the way you are implementing it. You need to load the array into the state and then you can pass it to the components used to show the data

Comment: thanks, yes I think adding what I did so far would make a difference, so I edited my question and added what i have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable 'name' deals only with one name. your query returns an array. I'm not sure if it's suppose to be this way, so you can add this at the top, or replace [name, setName] with..

```
const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = useState([]);
```

then you have an array you can add the names to.

then change this part of your code - you can remove var tmpArray= [];

```
//printing the elements in array
for (var i=0; i< length; i++){              
  //console.log(response.data[i].firstname);               
  //tmpArray.push(response.data[i].firstname);
  setFirstNames(firstNames => [...firstNames, response.data[i].firstname] );                
}
```

this adds all the returned names into firstNames
you can then access the firstNames by putting {firstNames[x]} x being the index, in your html, or you can map all of them to html elements

```
{firstNames.map(function(name, index){
                  return <p> {name}</p>
                })
              }
```

Comment: hey @LeeRobinson, thank you so much for this, you definitely helped me to get started. your code was giving out, "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."
so i edited this:
`{firstNames.map(function(name, index){
                  return <p> {name}</p>
                })
              }`
to: (added index as the key and the warning went off)
`{firstNames.map(function(name, index){
                return <p key={index}> {name}</p>
                })
              }`

Comment: I forgot to add the key good work. Glad I could help :-)

Comment: however, when I do that, i can only see 1 record on the UI, there are 50 array objects, am I missing anything?

Comment: can you change your question to show your updated code???

Comment: sorry nvm i did figure out why it was storing only one record, i forgot to change "" to []. now thats done, on the UI, only the last record is shown instead of all, im guessing its because of the key value that i set?
here is my html code:
`{firstNames.map(function(names, index){
            return ( 
              <li key={index}>
                {names.cvx} - {names.FIRST_NAME} - {names.ADDRESS_CITY} 
            </li>
            )
          })
        }`

Comment: shouldn't be anything to do with the key, again could you post all the code. its hard to tell just from that little piece of code

Comment: thank you so much once @LeeRobinson, i did resolve that issue.
here's the new issue:
how do i add the header to my response data?
i tried to put in the map function, but i get multiple headers with each data. how to overcome this?

Comment: Hi bro I would say open a new question and again as its a different question from the one posted here, and remember to copy and paste the code!! More than happy to help

Comment: sure thing, i thought the same, and here's the link to my new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022740/how-to-add-headers-to-the-api-response-using-reactjs

Comment: <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
         </tr>
        </thead> MAP FUNCTION HERE.

Comment: So as above just add the table header before the map function, then in your map function you don't need to include it. If you include them in your map function then it will map a header to each row which is what is happening!

Comment: when I do that, headers are displayed when the page is loaded. 
I dont want that. It should only display when the user hits on search, then display the data along with the headers.

Comment: so you need to do conditional rendering. something like { if (firstnames.length()>0) {return <th>etc etc</th>; firstnames.map() etc etc } } google react conditional rendering

Comment: Hi @LeeRobinson, I dont know how do I contact you but could you check this question and see if you could answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71036734/th-position-sticky-not-working-with-when-overflow-is-enabled-reactjs