# how to add headers to the api response using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react js,
I have a home screen with search bar. where user retrieves an employee information by providing the id. here's the code for that.

```
const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = useState("");
<input
            value={name}
            type="text" 
            id="header-search"
            placeholder="Enter the search term"
            name={'id'}
            onChange={handleChange}
            />
        
        <button onClick={HandleSearch}>Search</button>

const handleChange= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

const HandleSearch = e => {

    
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/search?id=`+name)
        .then(response => {
          setLoading(false);
          if(response.status == 200 && response != null){
            
              console.log("RES",response.data);
              var tmpArray= [];
              var tmpJsx =[];
              // I was checking to see if I could retrieve the data from my response.
              var dataparse = response.data;
              var length = dataparse.length;
              console.log("length of my response array is: "+length)

              //printing the elements in array
              for (var i=0; i< length; i++){
                
                //console.log(response.data[i].firstname);
                
                 setFirstNames((firstNames) => [...firstNames, response.data[i]]);
                
              }

              
          } else{
                console.log('problem fetching');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log("error occured: "+error);
        });
}
```

and here's my return function:

```
{firstNames.map(function (names, index) {
                  return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                      <td> {names.firstname} -</td>
                      <td> {names.lastname}</td>
                    </tr>
                   )
                })}
```

How do I add the headers to this data.
for example

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
```

i tried to put this in the map function, but then my data was looking like:

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
firstname lastname
def        deflast
firstname lastname
ghi        ghilast
```

Im sure there is something that im missing, could anyone help me on how to achieve this: thank you.

```
firstname lastname
abc        abclast
def        deflast
ghi        ghilast
```

Comment: when I do that, headers are displayed on the home page. 
I want them to be displayed only when user hits on search and then display the data along with the headers.

Comment: If i understand right your backend is returning an array of objects ? Object having first name and last name. If so, you can append at index 1 a custom object that has harcoded values like "First Name" and "Last Name" to display.
Also if by "headers" you mean like table headers I would suggest to change the wording as it sounds like HTTP headers at first glance.

Comment: you can do conditional rendering like {firstNames.length > 0 && put the headers here}

Comment: that's correct, backend returns an array of objects.
Could you give me an example on how to do a conditional rendering?

Comment: @cmgchess has given an answer for conditional rendering, but you can find docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a conditional rendering by checking if the array has length greater than 0

An example would be like this. You can apply similarly to your problem

```js
let names = [
  {firstName: 'John',lastName: 'Cena'},
  {firstName: 'Rey',lastName: 'Mysterio'},
]

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {names.length > 0 && <table> //table renders only when array has elements 
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>   //setting headers
        <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        {names.map((name,index) => {       //mapping for individual rows
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{name.firstName}</td>
              <td>{name.lastName}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-dpx6o?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: perfect, this helped. thank you sir.

Comment: how do I export the table data thats returned to a csv file?